# I need to Update my Kindle for PC Library but I have to do it without an internet connection

Tags: sync, kindle, connection

I have two computers, both with the Kindle for PC app, and one Android tablet with the Kindle for Android app. One computer has no internet connection. I need to update my library on the computer with no internet connection, but it obviously wont sync without a connection. Is there a way to transfer my books from one PC to the other, or from my Android to my PC?